# How can I run the "black box algorithms" in "computer readable format" found in the Atlas of Finite Group Representations?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

The [Atlas of Finite Group Representations](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/) has, among other things, generators in matrix form (over fields of positive characteristic, I think) for some groups.

([Example](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/alt/A5/mtx/A5G1-f4r2aB0.m1) in MeatAxe text format. [Example](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/alt/A5/bin/A5G1-f4r2aB0.b1) in MeatAxe binary format. I've used [MeatAxe](http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~MTX/) to multiply and print out matrices like these.)

Some groups, however, don't have explicit generators. What they sometimes have is a "black box algorithm" (in "computer readable format") to find generators.

Here's an [example](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/spor/M/words/MG1-find1) of such a computer readable program that finds generators of the [Monster group](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/M/). **How can I run programs like this one? Is it a MeatAxe, or GAP or Magma program?**

```
# Black box algorithm to find standard generators of the Fischer-Griess
# Monster group M.

  set F 0
  set G 0
  set V 0
lbl SEMISTD
  rand 1
  ord 1 A
  incr V
  if V gt 1000 then timeout
  if A notin 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 &
      20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 &
      35 36 38 39 40 41 42 44 45 46 47 48 50 51 52 &
      54 55 56 57 59 60 62 66 68 69 70 71 78 84 87 &
      88 92 93 94 95 104 105 110 119 then fail
  if F eq 0 then
    if A in 34 38 50 54 62 68 94 104 110 then
      div A 2 B
      pwr B 1 2
      set F 1
    endif
  endif
  if G eq 0 then
    if A in 9 18 27 36 45 54 then
      div A 3 C
      pwr C 1 3
      set G 1
    endif
  endif

  if F eq 0 then jmp SEMISTD
  if G eq 0 then jmp SEMISTD

  set X 0
lbl CONJUGATE
  incr X
  if X gt 1000 then timeout
  rand 4
  cjr 3 4
  mu 2 3 5
  ord 5 D
  if D notin 3 6 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 &
      23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 &
      38 39 40 41 42 45 46 48 50 51 55 56 60 62 &
      66 68 69 70 71 78 84 88 94 104 105 then fail
  if D noteq 29 then jmp CONJUGATE

  oup 2 2 3
```

Answer (score 4):

The answer, as always, is rtfm! :)  If you read [this page](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/info/blackbox.html), the authors state that the algorithms are implemented in a language called *BBOX*.  There's an interpreter for *GAP* on [this page](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/info/interpret.html).

Comment: I laughed. Thanks!